Help regarding a matlab code of Large intelligent surfaces
For my 8th sem project, i was referring to a matlab implementation of a Paper-Transmission Through Large Intelligent Surfaces:A New Frontier in Wireless Communications by Ertugrul Basar.
While  going through the matlab code, there are few lines which i am not able to understand, kindly help me please
SNR =20;

N=32; %Number of reflecting elements in LIS

M=2; % M-QAM order

bpcu = log2(M); %bits per channel use(SE)

bits_total = bpcu*8e5; %total number of bits

decoded = zeros(1, bits_total);

bit_seq = randi(2,1,bits_total)-1; %bit_sequence

sigma = 1/sqrt(2*(10^(SNR/10))); %SNR = Es/NP (Es = 1) noise samples~CN(0,NP) NP: noise power = 2*sigma^2

ss =qammod(0:M-1,M,'Gray');

ss = ss./sqrt(mean(abs(ss).^2));

kk = 1;

for iteration=1:bits_total/bpcu 

    bits=bit_seq(kk:kk+bpcu-1);

    %Binary2dec & symbols

    dec = sum(bits(1:log2(M))).*[2.^

(log2(M)-1:-1:0)])+1;

    xx = ss(dec);

Half code only- this for loop part, where we convert Binary to decimal, why we need this long equation.Any alternative or anyone who can actually help me understand this equation.
also i dont get why he did- bits=bit_seq(kk:kk+bpcu-1); like this will only result in 1 if i am correct?
This is only 30%of code i pasted because whole code is a bit large

Is M-QAM order always 2?

No, its taken as 2 for BPSK

So, coding is not fixed for (t)his implementation only (try what "bits" calculation results with using different values for N or/and M)?

1.-
The paper mentioned in this question is
Transmission Through Large Intelligent Surfaces: A New Frontier in Wireless Communications
link was published in 2019 at the European Conference on Networks and Communications (EuCNC).
Author : Ertugrul Basar
DOI: 10.1109/EuCNC.2019.8801961
It is also freely available here : ArXiV - Transmission Through Large Intelligent Surfaces: A New Frontier in Wireless Communications.
2.-
At NO point in this paper M-QAM with M=2 is mentioned.
QAM is an In-phase and Quatradure modulation thus QAM ALWAYS starts with 4 points.
The term QUADRATURE precisely implies that at least, the smallest QAM constellation has to have 4 points, the prefix comes from Latin : Quatuor : 4.
3.-
QAM Basics available at Wikipedia - Quadrature Amplitude Modulation.
While refreshing QAM basics note that there are square QAM constellations, and then there are constellation with added points, or missing corners.
One thing is what we learn at university on 1st contact and then you have proprietary modulations that may have custom/changing constellations among many other variations away from the standard core taught on arrival to the subject.

Why not write the names of the papers instead of "jut links"? Think 10 years form now, links might not work. The name is always searchable.

Added DOI and name of author, thanks for comment.
